# How to track set of pages with common URL in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, domains, google-search-console, url, traffic

I want to see how many people visit some forms on my website. Since I have around a thousand forms, I just want to check how many people visited any of these forms that share the same URL, save for the form number. It looks something like this:

```
websitename.com/Form/FolderName/FormNumbers
```

Everything up to and including ForderName is the same for all the forms - is there a way I can filter this and only read incoming traffic/referrals, etc for all of these forms?

Should I set up a custom report somehow, or is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this directly in your All Pages report by including an Advanced filter with a regex match like the following:

[image]

This matches any domain name (eg. websitename.com) and also any form number.

Comment: I understand how to do this in a custom report, but how would I add it to my All Pages report?

Comment: In the search box that says "advanced" beside it, just to the upper right of the report table.